# Exception thrown at 0x6D4DE559 (ucrtbased.dll) in firstapp1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c, memory

I have looked this up online and I could only find threads for C++, while i'm using C, so I come and ask, sorry if duplicate.

I'm still learning and I'm trying to understand

I just learned about strcpy and strcmp, but my brain simply can't process why the following code won't work;

```
void ifelse();
char nametype[100]; 
char typeofname[100];
char truth[100];

int main() {

    char name[100];
    int age;


    printf("\n Print \n");
    ifelse();
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age > 50) {
        strcpy(truth[100], "and you are an old person.");
    }
    if (age < 50) {
        strcpy(truth[100], "and you are relatively young.");
    }
    else {
        strcpy(truth[100], "and you're a middle age person with issues...");
    } 

    printf("Hello, your %s is %s, %s", nametype, name, truth);

    return 0;
}

void ifelse() {

    printf("Enter your name type (firstname/lastname): ");
    fgets(typeofname, 100, stdin);
    if (strcmp(typeofname, "firstname") == 0) {
        strcpy(nametype[100], "first name");
    }
    if (strcmp(typeofname, "lastname") == 0) {
        strcpy(nametype[100], "last name");
    }
}
```

within the if if and else statements I get an error while trying to copy the string called "truth", I also tried typing strncpy just in case, but nope.

it's supposed to continue to the print function at the bottom but either it won't print the variables or it's gonna output an allocation error

Comment: Where is the `ifelse();` function defined? Turn on compiler warnings `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang, `/W3` for VS, and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly, without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy` accepts two pointers to buffers, or in other words - arrays. `truth[100]` is not a pointer to a buffer, it is an element just after the array. So proper calls should be like below:

```
strcpy(truth, "and you are an old person.");
strcpy(nametype, "first name");
```

Make correct all similar calls in your code.

Comment: that fixed the problem, thank you.
If you can help em again, I have another issue

when I run the full code with the edit you proposed, this happens:

Console:

Enter your name type (firstname/lastname): firstname                                                                    Enter your name: Bruce                                                                                          Enter your age: 18  

final print:
Hello, your  is Bruce                                                                                                 , and you are relatively young.

Comment: As I remember `fgets` fills provided buffer `typeofname` with `\n` char in the end. So comparison "firstname\n" with "firstname" happens and nonzero returned.

Comment: is there any way to cancel out the \n?

Comment: No. `\n` pushed to the line when you press Enter. Your code should check the last input char in the string and remove `\n` if it is necessary.